# Embedding Kubernetes Dashboard UI in an Iframe

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am trying to embed Kubernetes Dashboard UI in an iFrame. I am able to see the login page, but when I try to login by providing the token, it does not load the dashboard and I stay on the Login Page itself. I suspect it has to do something with CORS and Access-Control-Allow-Origin setting.

Can someone tell how to make the right configuration so that I can access the Kubernetes Dashboard UI in an iFrame. I am able to access the UI without iFrame perfectly

In the iFrame, I get the following error in Javascript Console when I login via iFrame

```
“jweToken” has been rejected because it is in a cross-site context and its “SameSite” is “Lax” or “Strict”.
```

Comment: Have you tried to enable the browser's dev mode ? Do you have any errors ?

Comment: I am gettingthis error when I login in iFrame

Cookie “jweToken” has been rejected because it is in a cross-site context and its “SameSite” is “Lax” or “Strict”.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ingress to expose the dashboard service and add CORS annotations to allow more origins (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors). Note that if you are using the dashboard's helm chart, it already contains an ingress, so you can directly add annotations using the `ingress.annotations` value.

There is some other solutions:

- Modify the apiserver's command line to allow your origin (see https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/), but this one is somehow risky as you will change the policy for the whole API.
- Add a very simple deployment that will proxy the dashboard (using nodejs you can build a proxy with a few lines only), but this one requires some code of your own.